# What's the point in appending your CV to your Master's thesis?

Tags: thesis

Several Master theses in my department contain a CV of their author. I don't really see the point in doing that - anyone you're sending your thesis to that would need your CV, you'll probably be sending your CV already anyways. So why do people do that?

(I've edited this question so it's less of a 'does your university do that' kind of thing - sorry to the guys who already answered.)

Comment: The standard question: what is the opinion of your advisor about this? And in what field are you writing your master thesis?

Comment: What would you even put in there? Your high school grades and the student exchange you did back in fifth grade? If you have any uncommon things to mention (e.g. accepted publications during the masters), you might put this in. But then again, this can't be common practice, see the word "uncommon" above.

Comment: This will likely vary by country and school.  The ONLY place where you'll get an accurate answer is the office of your Dean of Graduate Studies, or local equivalent.

Comment: To clarify: I'm not asking whether I should put a CV into my Master's thesis. To me it looks odd and my advisor never told me to do so. I'm just wondering why people do it and whether it's standard.

Comment: In Germany in any fields I have been related to somehow this is not common. But honestly, this is somewhat of a "shopping question" as we already have two kind of contradicting answers (Forbidden in Vienna, but common in the rest of Austria?!) and any result will only be a list of information about separate countries/fields.

Comment: @skymningen I figured that somewhere on the internet, there might be a person who'd know why on earth people put their CV into a thesis, and whether it would look odd to high-ranking institutions to find a Master's thesis with or without a CV. I don't see how that makes it a shopping question. I would think that anyone who looks at Master's theses a lot (say someone who chooses whether or not to admit phd students) will have seen enough Master's theses to know whether it's common or not and whether there's any point to it.

Comment: I have no idea why either would look odd. If someone looks at a thesis with no intention of hiring the author, they probably don't care. If they have theintention of hiring the author, I would think that scanning through their CV actually happened before deciding to spend the time and actually have a look at the thesis.

Comment: @skymningen Yes, but then why include it in the first place? There has to be _some_ reason. Narcissism?

Comment: The only reason I could think of is the idea, that with a bachelor/masters thesis, the author often does not yet have any "standing" in research, so is an unknown to potential readers. (If you read a paper, you usually expect to find some information online about the authors, there is an affiliation and you can at least determine their main field of interest.) Still, as far as I know those thesis are rarely read (unless they have been published online and turn up as a search result for you, some collaborator gave their students thesis to you or you are planning to hire the student.)

Comment: @skymningen it's not forbidden everywhere in vienna, it's even mandatory at TU Wien.

Comment: @skymningen: "If someone looks at a thesis with no intention of hiring the author, they probably don't care." - is it only about hiring? When I've encountered a CV attached to a thesis, I instinctively always saw it as the equivalent of a brief presentation of the author's background as it is common e.g. in novels, especially hardcover ones.

Answer (score 4):

At the University of Vienna, it has been forbidden to add a CV to master's or PhD theses since 2016 (see e. g. here: http://web.archive.org/web/20170415151405/https://ssc-lebenswissenschaften.univie.ac.at/formulare-und-infoblaetter-download/diplom-und-masterstudium/).

Internationally, I have seen this practice very often, though I cannot see a clear advantage of it (I think most people would prefer not to look through a long thesis to find a CV, but would rather look for it on your homepage).

Comment: It is also not a requirement at Texas A&M. The OP should consult their university for their rules on theses and dissertations.

Comment: Well, it seems like it's only forbidden since you need to send it to a plagiarism checker. And not everyone got a homepage.

Comment: As it was necessary to publish this rule, it seems that putting a CV into the thesis was common before 2016

Answer (score 2):

Here in Austria it is common practice to add it to your masters thesis and it's mandatory at most universities in a PhD thesis.

The benefit is that the reader can get some information about the author.

Comment: At ETH Zurich I had to add a CV to the hard copies of my PhD thesis and to remove it for the online PDF version.